# Can you alias a template members in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, naming-conventions, alias

I want to rename or alias some parts of the stl so they are compliant with the naming conventions of my project.
So far renaming types is easy

```
template<class Type>
using Vector = std::vector<Type>;
```

I tried doing something similar to alias members:

```
template<class Type>
using Vector::PushBack = std::vector<Type>::push_back;
// and
template<class Type>
using Vector<Type>::PushBack = std::vector<Type>::push_back;
```

Sadly this approach does not work for member variables.
Can I alias members? How?

Comment: So you can do `PushBack(v, x)`, but not `v.PushBack(x)`.

Comment: I suggest you bite the bullet and use the standard types with their existing naming conventions. It makes your code easier to understand for any programmer that is already C++ savvy.

Comment: @L.F I'm sorry but, as far as I know, the title is correctly written down, a function can be a member of a class in C++. 'push_back' is a function, is part of the template class std::vector, therefore is a member of that class.

Comment: @RobertoP.Romero There is no problem with your title (except that the member function is technically not a template but a *templated entity*).  I'm replying to the "can I alias members" question.

Comment: @L.F. Fair enough

Comment: "Funny" that most naming conventions I encounter are incompatible with standard library. (and so "our" types has different conventions than std types).

Comment: fwiw, I would adjust your naming conventions rather than the names of `std` stuff. Or just be fine with it. Imho it is an advantage when `std` types stand out and can be distinguished from custom types that follow a different naming convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't alias member variables.

Cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/aliases-and-typedefs-cpp?view=vs-2019: "You can use an alias declaration to declare a name to use as a synonym for a previously declared type"

What is the point of aliasing a variable, since you can directly call it?

Answer (score 3):

You can only [alias types or type templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). A member function is not a type, thereofore you cannot alias it. However you can make a surrogate for it:

```
template <typename T>
auto push_back(std::vector<T>& vec, T&& val)
{
    return vec.push_back(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```